# How can I reduce nested if statements in the python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
if flask.request.form['token'] == stored_token:
    if size_of_file > 10000:
        logging.info('data ' + filename + ' is compressed and sent')
        return gzip_compress(resp(200, data))
    else:
        logging.info(filename + ' data copy')
        return resp(200, data)
else:
    logging.info(' data ' + filename + ' is not compressed, but copied and sent')
    return resp(401, {})
```

I do not like how this code looks to help fix it. Or tell me that this is a good code.

Comment: *you think* does not mean it is bad. This is just a nested `if` statement. who said it is bad??

Comment: If you have questions about the quality of code, consider posting your question the [code review forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Anyway I do not see any problem with this code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
if flask.request.form['token'] != stored_token:
    logging.info(' data ' + filename + ' is not compressed, but copied and sent')
    return resp(401, {})

if size_of_file <= 10000:
    logging.info(filename + ' data copy')
    return resp(200, data)

logging.info('data ' + filename + ' is compressed and sent')
return gzip_compress(resp(200, data))
```

In google testing blog there is an [article](https://testing.googleblog.com/2017/06/code-health-reduce-nesting-reduce.html) describing why nested `if` statements are considered bad and how can you reduce your code complexity.